# when to use pages and app folder in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm new in Nextjs13 and I'm confused in `pages` and app `directory`
can you clear me when we must to create page in `pages` folder and`app` folder?
If I don't use `pages` and build and export the project for deploying I can't see .html files in `out folder`

I know we can use together

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use app folder, each folder inside may represent an url path.

- app/foo stands for /foo

but to make /foo a public route, ... you MUST add page.tsx file. This is what I know about Next13